# Test second activity without logging in every time

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

User logs in or registers in first activity, then a new activity is displayed, which I am working on. Can I access this second activity in emulator or device without adding dummy user data to the code, or typing every time? I created an Espresso test to test login, but when the second activity is succesfully opened, test is passed and app logically closes.

Comment: You have to add more description about the login. As you can have your own/native login, or you're using server authentication (then probably you're saving some token), how do you identify logged in user? In more general way you can save test/dummy user credentials in the code (you could isolate this with separate build flavor).

Comment: I am using Firebase Authentication. User inputs email and password, callback receives email and userID.

Comment: On my previous project we used hardcoded user id for authentication and stored that in different git branch which always up to date with dev and switching branches before commit. It saves some time and movements (credential typing). Soon we will change this in favor of gradle flavors, for existing_user (without manual login) and not_existing_user (with login). If you'll find out better solution, please update the post.